# DecimalFormat format is removing leading 0 before decimal point

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
static DecimalFormat df4 = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");

Double a = 3591000;
Double d = a/10000000;
String str = df4.format(d);
```

Here i am expecting 0.3591, but df4.format is removing 0 before decimal. printing .3591

Comment: How to get 0.3591

Comment: So the next rational thing to do is to read the documentation to understand your mistake and fix it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: if your pattern is #,###.##   , change it to  #,##0.##  that will work

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
static DecimalFormat df4 = new DecimalFormat("0.0000")
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> # : zero shows as absent

while `0` does not.

Comment: Its working thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you so much!